# TableAdapter Provider uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient regardless of ProviderName being set

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, web-config, connection-string

I am trying to create a new TableAdapter using the connectionstring added in Web.config, and to minimize any chance of incompatibilities with existing libraries, I want my provider to be `System.Data.SqlClient` (like all other TableAdapters in this legacy system).

However, when I chooses the "MyConnection" as the Data Connection, the provider of the TableAdapter is still set to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, which forces me to install a bunch of new related packages.

I could not find any local config file that overwrites this connectionString. I've tried to uninstall `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package but when I create a new TableAdapter it will install it back. How could I fix this?

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
            Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;" 
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
  </configSections>
<configuration>
```

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2022 v17.7.4
and .NET Framework 4.8

Might be related, but I can't figure out how to make it work: [How to get Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to work with DataSet Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222515/how-to-get-microsoft-data-sqlclient-to-work-with-dataset-designer)

Comment: Possibly related, [Visual Studio 2022, it automatically adds NuGet Package for Microsoft.Data.SQLClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76423327)

Comment: Oh... That's a bad news, hopefully we wouldn't need to migrate from one to another...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the Microsoft release notes did not mention this behavior at all (at least I couldn't find any), since Visual Studio 2022 `v17.5` it will use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient even when the provider is being set to `System.Data.SqlClient` when you add a Table Adapter or DataSet which forces you to install a bunch of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` related package . (Seems to be an issue, [Issue#1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1300723/when-adding-dataset-in-asp-net-framework-4-7-2-pro), [Issue#2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2022-forces-using-Microsof/10462982?entry=problem&q=Unable%20to%20cast%20object%20of%20type%20%27System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand%27%20to%20type%20%27Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand%27))

As a pretty bad work around, we can manually change the provider back in the `properties` tab of the new tableAdapters in the data set designer, even though it's still going to force install all those new packages.

---

**Edit:**
Turns out while we can create a DataSet using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` first and change it back, we would still need to properly account the breaking changes for `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`, including [errors caused by untrusted certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17615260/9107694), even though in some cases (localhost, for instance) you don't care about encrypting at all.